# Execute as .test rather than ./test

Tags: filenames, executable

Supposing I am in the same folder as an executable file, I would need to type this to execute it:

```
./file
```

I would rather not have to type <kbd>/</kbd>, because <kbd>/</kbd> is difficult for me to type.

Is there an easier way to execute a file? Ideally just some simple syntax like:

```
.file
```

or something else but easier than having to insert the <kbd>/</kbd> character there.

Perhaps there is some way to put something in the `/bin` directory, or create an alias for the interpreter, so that I could use:

```
p file
```

Comment: Maybe swap / with another key using xmodmap? So at least it's easier to type

Comment: As a side note, `/` is used *extensively* in Unix, largely as a directory separator. You are probably better off finding an easier way to type it.

Comment: @RossPresser This question makes very little sense since . and ./ at the beginning of the file are two completely different meanings for technical reasons any beginner should know. `/` is not difficult to type for the vast majority of people, and if OP has an injury which prevents this, they should consider alternate keyboard layouts, since there is no way they can avoid `/` completely while in the terminal.

Comment: @JFA The majority of keyboard layouts used in continental Europe as well as South America put `/` on shift-7 which is comparatively difficult to type, even without an injury.

Comment: @nitro2k01 Sure, and they have the left control key out of the way, whereas the almost entirely useless caps lock key is sitting in a handy location.  I swap caps lock and control, so there's no reason why people can't swap / and whatever's on the left left of shift.

Comment: @DrEval Sure, you can remap anything to anything, but that's not what I was commenting on.

Comment: Edit history: "*why cant Network Interface be simply instructed
 to make all internet queries through a remote host
 via ssh on port 22.*" ಠ_ಠ

Comment: I use the numpad / instead of shift-7, I find it faster to type.

Comment: @OskarSkog What I've done on my linux boxes is to use the US layout then if I need to type *en français*, I use the compose key. Works great.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It can be "risky" but you could just have . in your PATH.

As has been said in others, this can be dangerous so always ensure . is at the end of the PATH rather than the beginning.

Comment: Don't really see how that's "risky": my path has been that way since long before linux, and it has never caused the slightest problem.

Comment: @jamesqf It is risky because if you `cd` to a directory that is world writable and try to use a command that is not in your path, you might execute a (possibly malicious) executable by the same name that someone wrote to that path. This is much worse if you put `.` at the beginning of your path. In that case, a malicious executable called `ls` would be executed if you try to call `ls` in that directory.

Comment: Please avoid this, for the reasons specified above. The `p` command would be better.

Comment: @jamesqf When it's "your" system, and only you use it, it's not so bad. The problem comes (and has tripped many a Unix admin over the years) on multi-user system. With a `.` early in the `PATH`, all a malicious user needs to do is drop a fake `ls` command in their directory and persuade the admin to "look at something weird" and they've got root access.

Comment: @TripeHound: Which I don't think would work on my system, because just about every common command is accessed through aliases.  E.g ls is aliased to "/usr/bin/ls -trF", cp is "/usr/bin/cp --preserve=mode,timestamps". Though I agree that it's much less of an issue if you're not a developer, and continually expect to run commands from the directory where you're working on them.

Comment: Good solution, although it won't work if the file happens to be named `test`, as in the question's title (since `test` is a shell built-in, and probably also exists somewhere in your `$PATH` already).

Answer (score 71):

**`.` will auto-complete to `./`** (type `.` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>) at least in modern Bash shells, so you shouldn't have to use a complex or insecure (like `PATH` modification) solution.

If it doesn't auto-complete you might need to install the "bash-completion" package.

Comment: Are you sure? `.` has multiple completion candidates: `.` (current dir), `..` (parent dir), the `.` command (which bash provides a nonstandard alias `source` for), and any dotfiles present. Maybe the `bash-completion` package ignores this; I find it atrociously annoying (e.g. it makes it impossible to tab-complete dir names in a `make` command line and is generally awful with makefiles full of implicit rules) so I always purge it.

Comment: I tried it, and yes, it does auto-complete this way. In almost every case that's what a regular user would want: I don't think I've ever seen a dotfile which should be executable, running something in a subdirectory is vastly more common than running something in a parent directory, and IMO it does a damn good job of finding `make` targets.

Comment: With bash 3.2 it does not autocomplete. Could this be new in bash 4?

Comment: @Calimo More likely new in recent versions of bash-completion. It's far from a fundamental change.

Answer (score 42):

> or.. perhaps giving the interpreter an alias in the bashrc file and then simply
>
> ```
>    p  file
> ```

It is possible to write such a function:

```
p() {
 ./"$@"
}
```

in your `~/.bashrc`. Then you'll be able to run `p app arguments` instead of `./app arguments`. This solution works for executables of any type, including scripts and binaries.

`"$@"` expands to appropriately quoted list of arguments passed to the function (preserving all special characters from glob or variable expansion), and, as @Scott pointed out, `bash` is clever enough to prepend `./` to the first one of them, preserving the rest.

Comment: Although it's less general for running app under another command, like `strace -f p app` to see system calls made, or `$(which time) p app` to see how long it takes.  `p` as a executable script would work better in these two specific examples I contrived.  Neither solution could work with `ldd p app`, albeit `ldd` _also_ differs in requiring a full path, perhaps for reasons like this.

Comment: Yes, replacing `p app args` with `./app args` in a way which is invisible to anyone would require piping shell input through some kind of preprocessor and would cause all sorts of fun when substitution occurs in an unintended place :)

Comment: In this case, shouldn't there be no quotes around `$@`? Otherwise it will just pass one big argument to the program.

Comment: @Kroltan No. `$@` is an array. When expanded within `"`, each parameter expands to a separate word. `$*` behaves the way you're thinking.

Comment: I believe that you’ve made this unnecessarily complex, and that `p() { ./"$@"; }` is all you need.

Answer (score 11):

You could put `.` to your `$PATH` by adding e.g. `PATH=$PATH:.` to your `/etc/profile`, this way you can execute `file` just by writing `file`, unless it is in some other folder in your path (e.g. `/usr/bin/`). Note that this is generally not a good idea.

Why it's bad: Say you're in a situation where you don't fully trust the contents of a directory - you've downloaded it from somewhere dodgy and you want to investigate it before running it, or you're a sysadmin helping some user by looking in their home directory, etc. You want to list the directory, so you try to type ls, but oops, you make a typo, and ended up typing sl instead. The author of this malicious directory anticipated this and put a shell script in it called "sl" which runs 'rm -rf --no-preserve-root /' (or something more malicious like installing a rootkit).

(Thanks @Muzer for the explanation)

Comment: Though I wholehartedly agree, It's probably woth explaining exactly why this isn't a good idea.

Comment: Why it's bad: Say you're in a situation where you don't fully trust the contents of a directory - you've downloaded it from somewhere dodgy and you want to investigate it before running it, or you're a sysadmin helping some user by looking in their home directory, etc. You want to list the directory, so you try to type ls, but oops, you make a typo, and ended up typing sl instead. The author of this malicious directory anticipated this and put a shell script in it called "sl" which runs 'rm -rf --no-preserve-root /' (or something more malicious like installing a rootkit).

Comment: Worth explaining that if the current directory is at the beginning of $PATH, instead, the attacker could just override ls or other common commands

Comment: @Muzer _Huuuge_ tinfoil hats here.

Comment: @GillBates It's the sort of thing you would need to be wary of as a sysadmin who has to deal with actual and potentially malicious users, or someone who analyses suspicious archives for a living. If neither of those apply, then I agree with you. I still don't think it's a good habit to get into, though, because you never know when your circumstances will change, you get one of these jobs, and you'll endlessly curse yourself for having trained yourself to rely on insecure behaviour ;)

Answer (score 10):

You can call the interpreter, for example

```
bash test
```

In this case, the script will run even if it has neither a shebang line (eg `#!/bin/bash`) nor an executable bit. You will have to know the correct interpreter to run it also. You could read the shebang line of the file first to make sure you call the correct interpreter, for example if the shebang line says

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

you would call

```
python3 test
```

Comment: interpreter just interpret code, they won't run binary files

Comment: This answer is somewhat logical because perhaps the interpreter can be given an alias in the bashrc file.

Comment: @McKernel good point, it only works if there is an interpreter, not for compiled executables

Comment: there is an interpreter for compiled executables: `/lib/ld.so`

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know, there is no way to achieve it unless you include file in env path, so you could run it just typing: `file`

`.file` won't work since that is a different file name. It is a file called `.file` and not `./file`.

I sense that slash may be difficult to type for you because non-english layout, maybe? In that case, it also happens to me, so I frequently swap my keyboard layout to english by pressing Alt+Shift in Windows (I use Linux from ssh)

Answer (score 7):

People have suggested adding **`.`** to `PATH`,
which is dangerous because it creates a risk
that you will accidentally run a malicious program
planted in a world-writable directory. 
But, if you have executable programs in a few directories
that you own and are writable only by you,
then it’s safe (fairly safe?) to put ***those director(ies)*** into `PATH`,
by adding a line like

```
PATH=$PATH:~/dev/myprog1:~/dev/myprog2
```

to your `~/.bashrc` file. 
Of course this means that you can run a program from one of those directories
from anywhere in the filesystem. 
For example, you could `cd /etc` and type `foo`,
and it would run `~/dev/myprog1/foo`. 
This has the minor drawback
that you can’t have programs by the same name
in more than one of the directories. 
Specifically, if you have programs called `foo`
in both `~/dev/myprog1` and `~/dev/myprog2`,
you won’t be able to run the second one except by specifying a path. 
Likewise if you have a `~/dev/myprog1/cat` — but why would you want to?

---

Another approach, if you have just a few programs that you do this with,
is to define aliases for them:

```
alias gizmo='./gizmo'
alias gonzo='./gonzo'
```

Or you can call the aliases `.gizmo` and `.gonzo`
if you find that more intuitive.

Actually, this has, to an extent,
the same security risk as putting **`.`** into your `PATH`. 
If a malicious user can read your `.bashrc` and see your aliases,
then he might put malware called `gizmo` and `gonzo` in random directories
in the hopes that you will run it. 
It’s better to make these use absolute pathnames:

```
alias gizmo='~/dev/myprog1/gizmo'
alias gonzo='~/dev/myprog2/gonzo'
```

---

By the way, you should avoid naming an executable `test`,
because that is a shell builtin command,
and you can run a program by that name
only by specifying a path  or some other trick.

Comment: Alternatively you can make a recipe (if you use Makefiles that is) and do `make gizmo` or `make gonzo`.

Comment: I’m sorry, but I’m not sure I understand how that relates to the question or my answer.  Are you suggesting that the OP create a `Makefile` in each directory, such that the actions for `make gizmo` end by ***running*** `gizmo`?  (1) That seems like an awkward way of doing the same thing as the `p` function, suggested in the question, initially [implemented by aitap](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/342819/80216#342840), and refined by Scott.  (2) Can you pass arguments that way?  ISTM that `make gizmo arg1 arg2` is equivalent to `make gizmo; make arg1; make arg2`.

Comment: (1) Perhaps my assumption is wrong but it isn't clear to me OP wants eschew from using `./` in **every directory**. In my mind, he's developing something and just needs to run the produced program `./file` often. I really can't think of any other scenario where one would frequently need to run a local file and if he isn't running it frequently he'd not bother asking the question (he said *difficult* not *impossible*)

(2) [not really](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214575/passing-arguments-to-make-run) but you can pass the arguments in the recipe.

Comment: (1) Well, I guess we can agree that the OP’s motivation and the scope of his question are unclear. (2) Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3):

If we're allowed to start configuring things

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/bin
cat > ~/.local/bin/x << 'EOF'
#!/bin/sh
N="$1"
shift
exec "./$N" "$@"
EOF
chmod a+x ~/.local/bin/x
```

Most modern distros include ~/.local/bin in $PATH already (add `export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"` to your `~/.profile` if yours doesn't).  Then you can use `x file` to run `./file`.

Don't try to define a `.` command.  The command `. script` already runs `script` in the current shell.  This allows `script` to define environment variables for the current shell.

Comment: I think there may be a good suggestion in here, but there's no explanation of what any of this does. I could work it out, but an inexperienced user would have no chance.

Comment: There is no need to shift $1.  Just `exec "$@"`.

Comment: `$ (ln -s /bin/ls my-ls && exec my-ls) #
bash: exec: my-ls: not found`

Comment: (1) There is no need to `shift $1`; just `exec ./"$@"`. (2) Since you’re talking about a shell script, it’s a little pointless/misleading to advise people not to define a **`.`** command,  since it’s impossible to create a file called **`.`**. (It is possible, and very inadvisable, to define an alias or shell function called **`.`**.)

Answer (score 3):

To expand on Zanna's answer about interpreters (sorry, no rep for a comment): an "interpreter" for native executables (aka binary ELF files) is the dynamic loader (`ld.so`), but it typically does not understand the syntax you want:

```
$ /usr/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 program
program: error while loading shared libraries: program: cannot open shared object file
$ /usr/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ./program
<program is launched>
```

(also, unless you symlink `ld.so` into your path, you'd still need to write `/`s)

Comment: This is Linux-specific, right? Could you please explain this more, why this works? I thought the (Linux) kernel would do the parsing and deciding whether and how to run a binary, that's what `binfmt_misc` is for.

Comment: @phk The file is Linux-specific, but the concept of a dynamic linker/loader is not. For instance, FreeBSD has its very own `/libexec/ld-elf.so.1`. On Linux, it's not as simple as "deciding how to run a binary": `binfmt_misc` detects format of the file by magic numbers (ELF, shebang script, CIL). After that, `binfmt_elf` handler is called. It parses ELF headers and sections; `.interp` section contains path of the dynamic loader; this loader is started by the kernel, does relocations, and jumps to `_start`. On FreeBSD (not sure about others) there's no binfmt, but the principle is +/- similar.

Comment: @phk as to why this works -- `ld.so` doesn't have `.interp` and is statically linked, which means it doesn't need for another dynamic linker/loader to resolve its external symbols and do relocation math.

Comment: ISTR Solaris also has something equivalent to this.

Answer (score 1):

If we're allowed to make helper scripts, you could make a helper that adds the pwd to the PATH, then run

```
. pathhelper    #adds pwd to path
file            #now it can be run without ./
```

This avoids adding "." to the path and polluting your .profile with every path you might at some point want to run something in.

We can take this approach a step further by making a helper that launches a new shell with a modified PATH.  If it takes a directory as a parameter (using the pwd as a default), it would function like a `pushd` that edits the path.  You might have to be mindful that any changes to other environment variables would be lost when exiting the subshell, but in a long-running shell your PATH variable won't get all cluttered up.  Depending on your workflows this might be advantageous.

```
:outer shell prompt$; subshellpathhelper    # launches a subshell with modified PATH
: subshell prompt $ ; file                  # in the subshell it can be run without ./
```

But I guess if you wanted to run with it you could hack `pushd` and `popd` so they can make the same modifications to the path without without making a subshell which will lose other changes.

```
pushd --path ~/some/path/    # normal pushd plus adds target to path
file                         # it can be run without ./ until you popd
```

(You can't do the same with `cd` because it doesn't have an analog to `popd`.)

You could also make a dedicated pair of helpers to just push and pop PATH entries.  What works best really depends on your usage patterns.

Comment: Actually, you could do something like it in `cd`, but it's further out there:  Make a file like `.dircmds`, and hack `cd` to make the commands defined in `./.dircmds` unavailable right before switching and available right after switching.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `. script.sh` syntax as long as the script you wish to execute is in the current directory.

You can also prefix with the interpreter, like sh or bash. 
example: `bash script.sh`

Comment: `. script.sh` will break if script contains `exit`, has unexpected effects e.g. if it redefined PATH "temporarily"; it also only works for scripts for your current shell

Comment: @sourcejedi Concerning `exit` you could put it in inside parentheses, i.e. a subshell, but true, it would still be only for scripts in the same shell.

Comment: The question says “an executable file”. These won’t work for a binary executable; only for a script.  And your second paragraph duplicates [Zanna’s answer](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/342819/23408#342825).

Comment: Well, my bad, I mostly execute and dev bash stuff, so I assumed we were talking about bash scripts :)

Comment: Not just only for a script, but only for a Bash script.

Comment: Is it equivalent to "source" command ? Because i used this one only to execute .bashrc script in the past :)